# how to do aggregate function with in another aggregate function in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am not that good in t-sql.. Please help...
I got table `Claims` and Columns are:

```
Client,BusinessType, cliamRefno
```

I want result like:

```
SELECT Client, BusinessType, COUNT(cliamRefno ), SUM(COUNT(cliamRefno )), 
COUNT(cliamRefno )/SUM(COUNT(cliamRefno )) FROM Claims GROUP BY Client, BusinessType
```

can Please anybody help? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to sum the counts over everything? (TotalCounts, not within the group of (Client, BusinessType))

Comment: I want count of ClaimRefno group by Client, BusinessType also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, and what I derive from your OP, try this for your needs. You'll want to subquery for the counts, then sum them in a window function to retain the grouping, but see the Counts you're looking for.

```
SELECT Client, BusinessType, Counts, SUM(Counts)OVER(), 
Counts/SUM(Counts)OVER()
FROM (
    SELECT Client, BusinessType, COUNT(cliamRefno) AS Counts
    FROM Claims
    GROUP BY Client, BusinessType
    ) T
```

Comment: @ Jaaz, thanks for the reply. I am getting wrong answer with Counts/SUM(Counts)OVER() column. 1/2 still I am getting 0

Comment: @user3583912: Could you set up something on SQLFiddle with sample data that's not coming out properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Claims TABLE (
    Client VARCHAR(50),
    BusinessType VARCHAR(50), 
    cliamRefno INT);
INSERT INTO @Claims VALUES('J Smith', 'Agricultural', 1);
INSERT INTO @Claims VALUES('D Brown', 'Agricultural', 2);
INSERT INTO @Claims VALUES('J Smith', 'Agricultural', 3);
INSERT INTO @Claims VALUES('Z Brown', 'Agricultural', 4);
WITH TotalClaims AS (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS TotalClaims
    FROM
        @Claims)
SELECT 
    c.Client, 
    c.BusinessType, 
    COUNT(c.cliamRefno) AS RefNoCount, 
    tc.TotalClaims AS TotalRefNoCount, 
    COUNT(c.cliamRefno) * 1.0 / tc.TotalClaims AS SomeAggregate
FROM 
    @Claims c
    CROSS JOIN TotalClaims tc
GROUP BY 
    c.Client, 
    c.BusinessType,
    tc.TotalClaims;
```